# Move files from applicationStorage to Documents in app

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I've got an app that, since 5 years now, that displays an offline map by reading from a folder embed in it ("assets").

Since Android 11, it's impossible to read from `ApplicationStorage` (`Error #3001: File or directory access denied`), so I'm trying to copy the folder from `applicationStorage` to "`Documents`".

What I did :

```
source = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/maps");
destination = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Documents/www");
source.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMapCopyComplete);
source.copyToAsync(destination, false);

function onMapCopyComplete(e: Event): void {
    source.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMapCopyComplete);

    log("onMapCopyComplete()");
}
```

I've got a return `onMapCopyComplete()` but when I'm looking in InternalStorage/Documents of my phone I've got the folders but all are empty... None of the files were copy..

[PrintScreen computer vs phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDkeE.png)

To read the files, here's what I'm doing :

```
   function startMapsView()
{
    var indexFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("www/index.html");
    
    if (!indexFile.exists) 
    {
        log("startMapsView() Index file not found, Please check www/index.html");
        return;
    }
    
    // Create StageWebView
    stageWebView = new StageWebView(isMobile);  // Set to TRUE for System's NativeWebView, FALSE is for AIR's WebView
    stageWebView.stage = stage;
    stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, iOSStatusBarHeight + headerBarHeight, deviceStageSize.width, deviceStageSize.height - (iOSStatusBarHeight + headerBarHeight + footerBarHeight));

    stageWebView.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onStageWebViewLoaded);
    stageWebView.addEventListener(flash.events.ErrorEvent.ERROR, onStageWebViewError);
    stageWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onStageWebViewLocationChanging);

    // Load Map URL
    stageWebView.loadURL(mapsURL);
}
```

And `mapsURL` is define by :

```
function setMapsURL(doNotEnableButtons: Boolean = false): void {
    var indexFile: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Documents/www/index.html");
trace("indexFile url is = "+indexFile.url);
    if (!indexFile.exists) {
        log("setMapsURL() Index file not found, Please check www/index.html");
        return;
    }

    var assetsDir: File;
    if (!useOnlineMaps) {
        assetsDir = new File(destination.resolvePath("index.html").nativePath);
    } else {
        assetsDir = new File(destination.resolvePath("onlineMaps.html").nativePath);
        mySavedData.data.onlineMapChoosen = false;
    }

    mapsURL = assetsDir.url;

    log("setMapsURL() " + mapsURL);

    if (!doNotEnableButtons) enableMapButtons();
}
```

Comment: It is just not possible that **Android** prohibits reading from the app directory, because the main **SWF** is also there and **AIR** runtime seems to read it with no problem. It is probably the way you read those files has a flaw. I encourage you to show that part of the script, because there are several different ways to do it, and not all of them are equally correct.

Comment: Ok. I'm just doing this to read the file (I'll also put it in the main post) : `function startMapsView()
{
 var indexFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("www/index.html");
 
 if (!indexFile.exists) 
 {
  log("startMapsView() Index file not found, Please check www/index.html");
  return;
 }`

Comment: Please explain, how these files get into **File.applicationStorageDirectory**? Because it is a place different from **File.applicationDirectory** where all the packaged files are supposed to be.